# Having problems baking normal texture for large object

Tags: texture-baking

I'm using Blender 2.93 nightly on Windows, and I have a kind of large model (500k triangles) that I'm trying to bake to a low-poly replica. I created the low-poly cylinder, positioned it on the model (just a bit larger), selected the model and the low-poly cylinder last, with the normals image already selected, and hit Bake. Blender sits at 0% for a while (about a minute?) and then with no errors, the bake status note vanishes. And the normals image is still all black (unmodified).

If I look at my task manager, I can see it's using 50% of my CPUs (16-core) and 30+ GB of my 32GB RAM, so it's hammering it pretty hard.

I tried both CPU and GPU bakes, same result. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Are there hidden places I should look for errors?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was just running out of RAM (and it's a lot more than 500k tris, maybe 50m tris). I decimated the whole thing, which took a long time, and then I could bake -- just barely.